# How to calculate the canonical divisor of projective space bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth variety, $E$ a rank $r$ vector bundle on $X$, $E^*$ its dual bundle, how do we show the canonical divisor can be expresses as $$K_{\mathbf{P}(E^*)}\cong \pi^*K_{X}\otimes O_{\mathbf{P} (E)^*}(-r)\otimes \pi^*\textrm{det}(E)$$

I think we can do this locally and check the gluing functions. But is there a clear way to see this?

Comment: Sadly I don't have the time now to write this up now, but luckily [one of Michael Thaddeus's answers on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/73531/33088) answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use $E$ instead of $E^*$, easier to write. Using the fact for $\mathbb{P}^n$ we have the Euler's sequence $0\to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to 0$, one can check that for $\pi:\mathbb{P}(E)\to X$, $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}(E)/X}$ is the kernel of the natural surjective map $\pi^*E(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}$. We also have an exact sequence of vector bundles $0\to \pi^*\Omega^1_X\to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}(E)}\to \Omega^!_{\mathbb{P}(E)/X}\to 0$. Taking determinants, we get that $K_{\mathbb{P}(E)}=\pi^*K_X\otimes \pi^*\det E(-r)$ where $r$ is the rank of $E$.